# Prove that a nontrivial subring of a ring that is a domain has the same identity

Tags: ring-theory

Let $R$ be a ring with an identity element $1_R$ which is a domain. Let $S$ be a nontrivial subring of $R$ with identity element $1_S$. Prove that $1_R = 1_S$.

Answer (score 5):

Hint: $1_S$ is an [idempotent element](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotent_element) of $R$, and it is $\neq 0$ since $S \neq 0$. What are the idempotent elements of a domain?

Comment: I'm guessing 1R? If so, is it the only idempotent element of R. If that is true then I can see how one can conclude 1R=1S

Comment: An integral domain has exactly two idempotent elements. Try to prove it just using the definitions, no ideas are needed.